# Not able to get text value from tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can anyone tell, how to get text fightname(Spicejet) as a string?

Tried code but giving me blank value

```
WebElement flightname= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top_first_part clearfix']/div[2]/span[1]")).getText();
```

also tried with javascript also but it giving me null value

Thanks in advance!!!

Url - https://flights.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/search/O/O/E/1/0/0/S/V0/DEL_BOM_08-08-2017?contains=false&remove=

[Image of tag FYI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fymWL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath you were using was not able to uniquely identify the container for first flight name. Try following:

```
WebElement flightname= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'clearfix listing_row')][1]//div[@class='top_first_part clearfix']//span[@class='pull-left airline_info_detls']/span[1]")).getText();
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working fine, I guess your **xpath** is wrong, it does not locate any Node. So try this. I hope it works for You.

```
driver.get("http://flights.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/search/O/O/E/1/0/0/S/V0/DEL_BOM_08-08-2017?contains=false&remove=");

WebElement Name= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='content']/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[2]/span[1]"));
String flightName= Name.getText();  
System.out.println(flightName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement Name=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[2]/span[1]"));
String flightName= Name.getText();

System.out.println(flightName);
```